# How can i send this page on Thank you After Sign up

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

//
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
dataType: "json",
data: {
"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
do_post: 1,
//title: title,
business_name: business_name,
address1: address1,
address2: address2,
city: city,
county: county,
postcode: postcode,
email: email,
//country_id: country_id,
//currency_id: currency_id,
phone: phone,
control_room_number: control_room_number,
customer_id: customer_id,
payment_terms: payment_terms,
service_type: service_type
},

```
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.code == "200") {

                alert("Success: " +data.msg);
                } if {

                    **console.log(data);
                    $(".display-error").html("<ul></ul>");
                    for ($i = 0; $i < data.message.length; $i++) {
                        $(".display-error").append("<ul>" + data.message[$i].msg +"</ul>");
                        $(".display-error").css("display", "block");
                    }
                    if
                    {
        
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});**//
```

Comment: you should have to write code in proper format

Comment: code is write between this characters ``` // code ```

Comment: I want to send this on thank you after submitting How can I do that?

Comment: In success function you can call alert or also configure popup model or toaster message. based on you requirement you can do that easily

Comment: I have to send user on thank you page which is another page after the display error is true(that means user fulfilled all the req field) I have to send user on another page that is my Thank you. alert message will show on the same page but i dont need that my requirement is to send user on thank you page after thy sign up and fill all the req fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
if(data.code === "200") {
   location.href = "http://www.example.com/ThankYou.html";
}
```

For the same tab you can use like below

```
if(data.code === "200") {
   window.open("http://www.example.com/ThankYou.html","_self");
}
```